# How to implement the right authentication method in my app?

Tags: authentication, token, whatsapp

I'm planning to code an mobile application and to use Xamarin for it.
However, I need some advice for the authentication procedure.
I was never advised in something like this before.

I want to keep the authentication procedure so simple as possible for the user.
I don't want to ask the user for the username and password.
I'm thinking about WhatsApp's solution. The user doesn't need to think about a username or password at the registration. The user needs to provide a phonenumber to verify it, only. After that, the user doesn't need to do anything later. It just works, without a username and a password.

My question to you guys, how did they realize it? Do they use a token based authentication? And the phonenumber as username and the IMEI number as the password?

Thank you all!

Best regards